# Swift 2.0: HTTP GET error handling in Xcode 7

Tags: http, get, swift2, xcode7

I'm new with xcode programming, I'm trying to implement an App in Swift 2 that makes an HTTP Get request. After upgrading xcode 7 its showing error of:

```
Cannot convert value of type 
'(NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, err: NSError!) -> ()'
to expected argument type 
'(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'
```

(This code snippet uses the old error handling of swift 1.2.) Can anyone help me please how to implement this in Swift 2.0.

```
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:loadedData)

    task.resume()


}

func loadedData(data:NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, err:NSError!){

    if(err != nil)
    {
        print(err?.description)
    }
    else
    {
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        print("\(httpResponse.statusCode)")

        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
        {

            jsonResult = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
            print(jsonResult)


            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SuccessSignin", sender: self)

        }
        else if (httpResponse.statusCode == 422){

            print("422 Error Occured...")
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method signature has changed (parameters are now optionals). Also, you have to use `try` enclosed in a `do catch` block. And avoid using forced try (with `!`) but prefer catching possible errors, and use `if let` to safely unwrap optionals. Example:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!.description)
    } else {
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    if let data = data, let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        print(jsonResult)
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SuccessSignin", sender: self)
                    }
                } catch let JSONError as NSError {
                    print(JSONError)
                }
            } else if (httpResponse.statusCode == 422) {
                print("422 Error Occured...")
            }
        } else {
            print("Can't cast response to NSHTTPURLResponse")
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the error message that you are receiving:

```
Cannot convert value of type 
'(NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, err: NSError!) -> ()'
to expected argument type 
'(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'
```

As is shown in the message, the parameters for the `dataTaskWithRequest`'s `completionHandler` changed from being *forced unwrapped* (`!`) to being just **optionals** (`?`).

Notice the `!` versus the `?`:

```
// old
(NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, err: NSError!)
// new
(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?)
```

As a result, you need to adjust your code accordingly.

For example, your method declaration will look like this:

```
func loadedData(data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, err:NSError?)
```

In addition, evaluate the method body and make sure that you are now properly unwrapping the optional parameters `data`, `response` and `err`.

See the [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:) class reference for more information.